# Make an <a> tag move onto a new line, without using "display:block"

Tags: css

I would like the navigation links on [this page](http://carolineelisa.com/) to each appear on their own line:

A. Without using "`display:block`" - as that makes the hover animation take up the full width of the container, not just the `<a>` element.

B. Without using `<br>` tags, as I am eventually looking to create a responsive site with a horizontal navigation on smaller screens.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: They already appear on their own line?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721031/css-force-new-line/22925271#22925271 helps?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Have you tried `float:left; clear:left` ?

Answer (score 5):

wrap you navigation in ul, li:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

`ul {list-style: none} li {display: block}`

This lets you style your anchors accordingly while forcing them to break lines.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response David, but I avoided using a list to make it easier to centre.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the `<a>`'s in `<div>`'s and apply CSS to the `div`'s to `float:left`, `clear:left`;

```
div.anchorContainer
{
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}

<div class="anchorContainer">
    <a href="#">text</a>
</div>

<div class="anchorContainer">
    <a href="#">text</a>
</div>

<div class="anchorContainer">
    <a href="#">text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but Cadence got there moments earlier!

Comment: @CarolineElisa You should evaluate accepting this answer as it is more elaborate and helped me faster than Cadence's.

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply `word-break: break-all;`

```css
.parent-block {
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.long-link {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-block">
<a class="long-link">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000674/make-an-a-tag-move-onto-a-new-line-without-using-displayblock</a>
</div>
```