# CSS force new line

Tags: css, css-float, newline

I have something like this:

```
<li>Post by <a>Author</a></li>
```

And I want to display the link in a new line, like this

```
Post by
Author
```

How can I achieve this? Clear:left doesn't work.

Comment: Use a breakline ? <br/>

Comment: li a { display:block}

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1672879/1111052

Comment: This is created by a plugin, if I could use a breakline, I wouldnt ask. Display:block doesnt work.

Comment: I'm sorry. Display block did work. My fault.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use the display property

```
a{
    display: block;
}
```

This will make the link to display in new line

If you want to remove list styling, use

```
li{
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: I have already made the link look like a button, and using `display:block;` makes the button too wide. How can I force the link to a new line while maintaining its width?

Comment: If you want to revert the effect, you can use `display:inline;` (for example in a media query).

Answer (score 34):

How about with a `:before` pseudoelement:

```
a:before {
  content: '\a';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: This is great for situations in which you want to put an anchor element on a new line, but not have its clickable area take up the entire line's width.

Comment: Loved your solution, even if I had a different problem than the one described here, Thank you!

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you. Solved one of those problems where the client requests something outrageous and you just gotta do it!

Comment: In case someone wonders (like I did): The `\a` renders as a newline, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33332670

Answer (score 1):

or you can use:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Comment: this will display on the same line... the question refers to a 'new line', in which case either inline or block will work. inline-block will attempt to place on the same vertical axis.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br />` OR `<br>` -

```
<li>Post by<br /><a>Author</a></li>
```

OR

```
<li>Post by<br><a>Author</a></li>
```

or

make the `a` element `display:block;`

```
<li>Post by <a style="display:block;">Author</a></li>
```

[Try](http://jsfiddle.net/EPqWQ/)

Comment: @PatsyIssa: Yes, But i didn't see them when post.

Comment: should be `<br/>` or `<br>`

Comment: @alxndr: Yes, you are right, there are some HTML syntax mistake. Please see updated answer. Thanks for your suggestions. :)

Comment: Try avoid styling with markup, like <br />. I'd use the above answers using the display property.

Comment: @veritascs: Yes, it's not a good approach to use markup for putting styling purposes.